# DateTime field gets wrong value in FireBase

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database

I am uploading smart meter data to FireBase.
I have an object with a datetime property like:

```
keys['datetime'] = datetime.now()
```

When I export the object generated at 4pm to JSON, I can see that the value is correct:

```
"datetime": "2018-10-26T16:00:06.348296"
```

However, when I upload the same object to FireBase, It goes 2 hours ahead:

```
26 October 2018 at 18:00:06 UTC+2
```

Can somebody give me a hint how to push the correct date? The source system is set to CET (Amsterdam time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Firebase documentation Firebase is expecting your timestamp to be in UTC time.

Comment: Thanks, so, the solution was `keys['datetime'] = datetime.utcnow()`